# Why my description is not visible on my public CV page?

Tags: bug, developer-story

I see it when I am logged in, but it's missing on my [public CV page](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/walidus).

I got @mail address in it. Is this a source of my problem? Or it is just a bug?